# Python Discord | Как замутить участника

Tags: python, discord

Я бы хотел замутить участника, да, я знаю что можно назначить участнику роль мута, но если сервер перезапустится во время ожидания, то эта роль навсегда останется у участника.

Я discord я видел функцию "Отправить участника подумать о своём поведении", плюс там есть таймер который показывает сколько осталось до окончания мута. Как можно реализовать эту функцию в python?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать команду `timeout`, в ней использовать функцию `timeout()`

```
@bot.command()
async def timeout(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason='Нарушение правил сервера')
    await member.timeout(until=указываете время на сколько мутить, reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Участник {member.mention} был замучен.\nПричина: {reason}')
```

Для работы со временем в `until` используйте модуль `datatime`. Подробнее в документации [discord.py timeout()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=timeout#discord.Member.timeout)

Comment: У меня есть такая проблема, он не считывает метод timeout(), будто его нет.